# How to override plugin's main property in Aurelia/Webpack skeleton?

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I am using [aurelia-gravatar](https://github.com/SpoonX/aurelia-gravatar-component) plugin in my [demo Aurelia/enhance](https://github.com/k2s/aurelia-skeleton-esnext-webpack-enhance) application based on webpack skeleton.

To make it work I have to manually add `"main": "dist/commonjs/index.js",` to `node_modules/aurelia-gravatar-component/package.json`.

Is there a way how to do this override from application `package.json` ? This is not working for me:

```
  "aurelia": {
    "build": {
      "resources": [
        "aurelia-gravatar-component/gravatar"
      ]
    },
    "moduleRootOverride": {
      "aurelia-gravatar-component": "dist/commonjs"
    }
  },
```

The error in browser is `Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-gravatar-component'.`.

How to quickly test the demo app:

```
# get the demo app
git clone https://github.com/k2s/aurelia-skeleton-esnext-webpack-enhance.git
cd aurelia-skeleton-esnext-webpack-enhance
npm install

# manually add '"main": "dist/commonjs/index.js",' to 'node_modules/aurelia-gravatar-component/package.json'

# start serving the application
npm start
# open the application in browser
xdg-open http://localhost:9000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may reference the main file directly, when dynamically importing the plugin. In your `src/main.js` file simply configure the plugin in the following way, until the project fixes their `package.json`:

```
aurelia.use
  .standardConfiguration()
  .developmentLogging()
  .plugin('aurelia-gravatar-component/dist/commonjs/index')
  .globalResources('hello')
```

You will also need to add that file to your `package.json`'s build resources:

```
"aurelia": {
  "build": {
    "resources": [
      "aurelia-gravatar-component/dist/commonjs/index",
      "aurelia-gravatar-component/dist/commonjs/gravatar"
    ]
  },
},
```

But ultimately `aurelia-gravatar` should define a `main` - feel free to file a bug report to that project.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it doesn't seam to work (https://github.com/k2s/aurelia-skeleton-esnext-webpack-enhance/commit/e575920aa9b396b23bf1fbca91c013f9279af35b). Would it not be better if `moduleRootOverride` would be supported ? aurelia-gravatar-component is now fixed (https://github.com/SpoonX/aurelia-gravatar-component/pull/9/commits/c05f6a2480ca07574be3c2eb45cf5a52b417a6d8), but in my opinion webpack plugin should allow this kind of customatization from main project.

Comment: @k2s since the component's `main` is fixed, all you need now is `"resources": [
        "aurelia-gravatar-component/gravatar"
      ]`. By default the root is overriden by the parent file of the main file.